# How do you access Blockchain's tor hidden service?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, proxy, network-configuration, firewall

I'm trying to access Blockchain's tor hidden service on tor in order to make a wallet over tor, but everytime I try to access the onion link they give me on blockchain's website, it always times out. It says "If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the web." Can someone help me. How do you configure your firewall or proxy to make sure Tor can access the web????

Comment: Can you let me know if http://expyuzz4wqqyqhjn.onion/ works for you using the Tor Browser?

Comment: I see that you asked the same question twice. The first step to troubleshooting a browser issue is to check to see if there is a problem with the browser or if there is a problem with the website. The url I gave you is to the torproject's homepage. Please let us know if you can access so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Yes I was able to access it..

Comment: @JSEvans Could you vote to close the other question, please?

Comment: Ok, I deleted it. Sorry..